# Getting each status change in a table

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, gaps-and-islands, query-performance

I have a table that holds status changes per item.  The item can go in and out of a status multiple times.

ItemTable (ItemId int, Status varchar(50), DateOfChange date)

I need to pull the date of each change. However, since the statuses can be repeated for each Item, I can't just do the min(DateOfChange) and find the occurrences.

This is in an OLAP environment, and the subquery that's been used to pull this data is KILLING performance.

Is there a way to pull this stuff via partitioning/rownumber functions?  Or something else that would behave better in OLAP? (This is in SQL 2008.)

Comment: To clarify, you need to pull the first date of each status for an item?

Comment: Sorry, power knocked out the office for about 10 hours.  :P  No, I need each date for each status change.  So if it goes into status A 5 times, I need 5 dates.  Be nice if it were just the first instance of A, but no such luck.

Comment: I had an answer lined up but Martin's is fleshed out a little better if that's what you were looking for. What doesn't quite make sense to me is you have a date per status per item in your table, what are you looking for?

Comment: 'Cause it's not just those columns; it's a metric ton of data per day, but this one column is all I care about for this crappy subquery.  Martin saved my bacon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of requirement comes under the banner of "gaps and islands". A popular approach is

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY DateOfChange) - 
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId, Status ORDER BY DateOfChange) AS Grp
         FROM   ItemTable)
SELECT ItemId,
       Status,
       MIN(DateOfChange) AS Start,
       MAX(DateOfChange) AS Finish
FROM   T
GROUP  BY ItemId,
          Status,
          Grp
ORDER  BY Start
```