# How to find duration in a dataset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a dataset of the following structure:

```
Target, PollTime, Value
------------------------
1. A, 2013-12-13 13:31:44.000, 15.00
2. A, 2013-12-13 13:32:44.000, 16.00
3. A, 2013-12-13 13:33:44.000, 16.00
4. A, 2013-12-13 13:34:44.000, NULL
5. A, 2013-12-13 13:35:44.000, NULL
6. A, 2013-12-13 13:36:44.000, 15.00
7. B, 2013-12-21 05:29:34.000, 3.00
8. B, 2013-12-21 05:30:34.000, NULL
9. B, 2013-12-21 05:31:34.000, NULL
10. B, 2013-12-21 05:32:34.000, NULL
11. B, 2013-12-21 05:33:34.000, 4.00
12. B, 2013-12-21 05:34:34.000, NULL
13. B, 2013-12-21 05:35:34.000, NULL
14. B, 2013-12-21 05:36:34.000, 5.00
```

I would like to build a resultset that groups the null values, showing the start, end time and duration. (Null means the target was unavialble).

```
Target, StartDate, EndDate, Duration(min)
---------------------------------------------
1. A, 2013-12-13 13:34:44.000,2013-12-13 13:36:44.000, 2
2. B, 2013-12-21 05:30:34.000,2013-12-21 05:33:34.000 3
3. B, 2013-12-21 05:34:34.000,2013-12-21 05:36:34.000, 2
```

The StartDate would be the first NULL Value, while the EndDate would be the next NON-NULL Value, and my duration calcualtion would be based on those two values.

Any clues to build this query would be great.

As I am thinking of joining the table to itself, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? In 2012, it will be easier.

Comment: We are still using 2008R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out, this is better solved by Gaps and Islands.

```
WITH T
 AS (SELECT *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Target ORDER BY PollTime) - 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Target, Value ORDER BY PollTime) AS Grp
     FROM   [schema].[Table] 
     )
SELECT Target,
       MIN(PollTime) AS Start,
       MAX(PollTime) AS Finish,
       DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(PollTime), MAX(PollTime)) AS Duration
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Target,
          Grp
HAVING MAX(Value) is null
ORDER  BY Start
```

Original source for code:  [Getting each status change in a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56593/getting-each-status-change-in-a-table/56594?noredirect=1#56594)

Comment: No, this will show only 2 rows, while the OP wants 3.

Comment: Ahhh, good point. This looks like a job for Gaps and Islands.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I much appreciate your solution, however this calcuates all nulls and doesn't group them. Hope that is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe move the WHERE clause from the CTE to the SELECT.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and come up with the same result that I am not looking for. Let's say I have one target, this target could have 4 nulls togther with november, then have values until december and then can have 3 null together. In that case I need two rows. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It needed a slight change in how the NULLs were filtered. It still doesn't match the desired output exactly, as it shows the first and last `PollTime` for a NULL set, rather than the first of the NULL set and the first of the following set. May do the trick, though, if a simple "+1" is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Please be aware that the query will not work correctly with 4 or more blocks of `NULL` for the same target [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d10c1/3)

Answer (score 4):

***For SQLServer 2008***
As the OP commented that he uses SQLServer 2008 the other query cannot be used.
At first I tried to convert them, then a new idea came to me

**Converted**

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT Target, PollTime, Value
       , ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Target ORDER BY PollTime)
       , IsNull = CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM   [Table1] 
), A AS (
  SELECT t1.Target
       , StartDate = t1.PollTime
       , EndDate = COALESCE(t3.PollTime, t1.PollTime)
       , t1.Value
       , Block = t1.ID - SUM(t2.IsNull)
  FROM   T t1
         INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.Target = t2.Target And t2.ID <= t1.ID
         LEFT  JOIN T t3 ON t1.Target = t3.Target And t3.ID = t1.ID + 1
  GROUP BY t1.Target, t1.PollTime, t1.Value, t1.ID, t3.id, t3.PollTime
)
SELECT Target
     , StartDate = MIN (StartDate)
     , EndDate = MAX(EndDate)
     , [Duration(min)] = DATEDIFF(mi, min(StartDate), max(EndDate))
FROM   A
WHERE  Value is Null
GROUP BY Target, Block
ORDER BY Target, Block
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c3b7/47)

Same idea of the queries for SQLServer 2012, get a rank for every block, the `LEAD` in this is the `LEFT  JOIN T t3 ON t1.Target = t3.Target And t3.ID = t1.ID + 1` and the A `CTE`

**Different idea**

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT Target, PollTime, Value
       , ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Target ORDER BY PollTime)
 FROM   [Table1] 
), B AS (
  SELECT t1.Target
       , ID1 = min(t1.ID)
       , ID2 = t2.ID
  FROM   T t1
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                      FROM   T i 
                      WHERE  i.Value is not null 
                        AND  i.Target = t1.Target
                        AND  i.ID > t1.ID
                      ORDER BY i.Target, i.ID) t2
  WHERE  t1.Value is Null
  GROUP BY t1.Target, t2.ID
)
SELECT b.Target
     , StartDate = MIN(t.PollTime)
     , EndDate = MAX(t.PollTime)
     , [Duration(min)] = datediff(mi, min(t.PollTime), max(t.PollTime))
FROM   B
       INNER JOIN T ON B.Target = T.Target And T.ID IN (b.ID1, b.ID2)
GROUP BY b.Target, b.ID2
ORDER BY b.target, b.ID2
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c3b7/46)

Why care about block ranking? Just get the first row where value is not null after the current one (in the `CROSS APPLY`) for a block of null it will be the same, so a `GROUP BY` can effectively be used to get the first ID of the null block (done in the B `CTE`).
Having the two ID getting the data is easily to derive.

***For SQLServer 2012***
I found two ways to get the result, but I haven't checked the performances.

**First one**

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT target
       , pollTime
       , Value
       , Block = SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                 OVER (Partition BY Target ORDER BY PollTime)
               * CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       , NextPollTime = LEAD(PollTime, 1, PollTime)
                        OVER (Partition BY Target ORDER BY PollTime)
  FROM   table1
)
SELECT target
     , StartDate = min(pollTime)
     , EndDate = max(NextPollTime)
     , [Duration(min)] = datediff(mi, min(pollTime), max(NextPollTime))
FROM   DATA
WHERE  Block > 0
GROUP BY target, block
ORDER BY target, block
```

The `* CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in the Block field is to have a number only for the block of `NULL`.
The `LEAD` is to get the value of the first row after the block of `NULL`

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1124a/24)

**Second one**

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT target
       , pollTime
       , Value
       , Block = SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                 OVER (Partition BY Target ORDER BY PollTime)
               - CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM   table1
)
SELECT target
     , StartDate = min(pollTime)
     , EndDate = max(pollTime)
     , [Duration(min)] = datediff(mi, min(pollTime), max(pollTime))

FROM   DATA
GROUP BY target, block
HAVING count(value) < count(1)
ORDER BY target, block
```

The `- CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` in the block field shift the rank by 1 row, the first row of the next block is now the last row of the `NULL` block.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1124a/26)

Comment: I tried both examples with 2008R2, I beleive LEAD isn't supported for the first example. And I was getting a syntax error with OVER (Partition BY Target ORDER BY PollTime) - it looks like the ORDEr BY. But this looks like an awesome example. Thank you.

Comment: @PeteDragun I have added two queries for 2008, if you want to check them. Thanks, finding a way to get those results in 2008 has been really interesting

Comment: The second answer works like a charm and is quite stable as well. The only exception is that I needed to change Block = SUM(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                 OVER (Partition BY Target ORDER BY PollTime) in yout 2012 examples, not 2008R2
               * CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, as shown in your first example. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an alternative `SQL Server 2008 R2` solution that is efficient when:

1. There are relatively few `NULLs`; and
2. The right supporting indexes are available

The gaps-and-islands method may be faster if:

1. The table is not too large (minimizing sorting costs); and
2. `NULLs` form a high proportion of the data.

**Sample data and required indexes**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
    [Target] char(1) NOT NULL, 
    [PollTime] datetime NOT NULL, 
    [Value] varchar(5) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ([Target], [PollTime])
);

-- Optional helpful filtered index to find NULL rows in required order
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fi1
ON dbo.Table1 ([Target], [PollTime]) 
INCLUDE (Value) 
WHERE Value IS NULL;

-- Sample data
INSERT dbo.Table1
    ([Target], [PollTime], [Value])
VALUES
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:31:44', '15.00'),
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:32:44', '16.00'),
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:33:44', '16.00'),
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:34:44', NULL),
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:35:44', NULL),
    ('A', '2013-12-13 13:36:44', '15.00'),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:29:34', '3.00'),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:30:34', NULL),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:31:34', NULL),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:32:34', NULL),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:33:34', '4.00'),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:34:34', NULL),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:35:34', NULL),
    ('B', '2013-12-21 05:36:34', '5.00');
```

**Solution step 1:**

```
-- Find start and end dates
SELECT
    T1.[Target],
    Calc.StartOrEnd,
    Calc.PollTime,
    GroupID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.[Target], T1.PollTime) + 1) / 2
INTO #PartialResult
FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- Classify the outer NULL row as start, end or neither
    SELECT TOP (1)
        StartOrEnd.StartOrEnd, 
        StartOrEnd.PollTime 
    FROM 
    (
        -- Start date test
        SELECT
            StartDate.StartOrEnd,
            StartDate.PollTime,
            StartDate.Value
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT TOP (1)
                -- Looking for a Start date (S)
                StartOrEnd = CONVERT(char(1), 'S'), 
                T1.PollTime,
                T2.Value
            FROM dbo.Table1 AS T2 
            WHERE 
                -- Find the previous row
                T2.[Target] = T1.[Target]
                AND T2.PollTime < T1.PollTime
            ORDER BY
                T2.PollTime DESC
        ) AS StartDate
        WHERE
            -- Is a Start date if the value isn't NULL
            StartDate.Value IS NOT NULL

        UNION ALL

        -- End date test
        SELECT
            EndDate.StartOrEnd,
            EndDate.PollTime,
            EndDate.Value 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT TOP (1)
                -- Looking for an End date (E)
                StartOrEnd = CONVERT(char(1), 'E'), 
                T2.PollTime,
                T2.Value
            FROM dbo.Table1 AS T2 
            WHERE 
                -- Find the following row
                T2.[Target] = T1.[Target]
                AND T2.PollTime > T1.PollTime
            ORDER BY
                T2.PollTime ASC
        ) AS EndDate
        WHERE
            -- Is an end date if the value isn't NULL
            EndDate.Value IS NOT NULL
    ) AS StartOrEnd
) AS Calc
WHERE 
    -- Outer row value is NULL
    T1.value IS NULL;
```

[image: Step 1 Query Plan]

**Solution step 2:**

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cuq
ON #PartialResult (GroupID, [Target], StartOrEnd);

-- Special case: final end row
-- if the last row in the table is NULL
INSERT #PartialResult
(
    [Target],
    StartOrEnd,
    PollTime,
    GroupID
)
SELECT
    FinalRow.[Target],
    StartOrEnd = CONVERT(char(1), 'E'),
    FinalRow.PollTime,
    GroupID = LastGroup.GroupID
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        T1.[Target],
        T1.PollTime,
        T1.Value
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1
    ORDER BY
        T1.[Target] DESC,
        T1.PollTime DESC
) AS FinalRow
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1) GroupID
    FROM #PartialResult
    ORDER BY GroupID DESC
)  AS LastGroup
WHERE
    FinalRow.Value IS NULL;
```

[image: Step 2 Query Plan]

**Solution step 3:**

```
-- Final result
SELECT
    Pivoted.[Target],
    StartDate = Pivoted.S,
    EndDate = Pivoted.E,
    Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Pivoted.S, Pivoted.E)
FROM #PartialResult
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(PollTime) 
    FOR StartOrEnd IN (S, E)
) AS Pivoted
ORDER BY
    Pivoted.GroupID;
```

[image: Step 3 Query Plan]

```
-- Tidy up
DROP TABLE 
    #PartialResult, 
    dbo.Table1;
```

**Results:**

```
╔════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ Target ║        StartDate        ║         EndDate         ║ Duration ║
╠════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ A      ║ 2013-12-13 13:34:44.000 ║ 2013-12-13 13:36:44.000 ║        2 ║
║ B      ║ 2013-12-21 05:30:34.000 ║ 2013-12-21 05:33:34.000 ║        3 ║
║ B      ║ 2013-12-21 05:34:34.000 ║ 2013-12-21 05:36:34.000 ║        2 ║
╚════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

I see answers with CTE, but since I do not really understand those...

```
select s.[Target], s.PollTime [StartDate], min(e.PollTime) [EndDate], datediff(minute,s.PollTime,min(e.PollTime)) [Duration(min)]
from 
    (select *, lag(value,1) over (partition by [Target] order by PollTime) [lag_Value]
    from #temp) s
join
    (select *, lag(value,1) over (partition by [Target] order by PollTime) [lag_Value]
    from #temp) e on s.[Target] = e.[Target] and s.PollTime < e.PollTime
where s.Value is null
and s.lag_Value is not null
and e.Value is not null
and e.lag_Value is null
group by s.[Target], s.PollTime
```

Just replace #temp with whatever your table name is.

Comment: Just saw you are using SQL Server 2008R2. Well, if you ever upgrade maybe this way can help. :)

Comment: `CTE` are subquery positioned before the main query to add readability, in your query both s and e can be defined as `CTE` just adding a WITH, as an example [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17524) is your query written with `CTE`

Comment: You are defining two identical subselects here. This is where using a CTE is helpful, because you can define your subselect as a CTE *once* and reference it multiple times (just like a view, except it is accessible in a single statement only). [Here's one more example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17537) for you, this one illustrating how a CTE is re-used.